# gcs_fuse_csi_driver_config unsupported block type

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

This is supported here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#gcs_fuse_csi_driver_config

and here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcs-fuse-csi-driver/blob/main/docs/terraform.md

I put it as seen in the cluster block below:

```
    resource "google_container_cluster" "primary-cluster" {
      enable_kubernetes_alpha  = false
      enable_legacy_abac       = false
      enable_shielded_nodes    = false
      remove_default_node_pool = true
      initial_node_count       = 1
      location                 = local.ws_vars["zone"]
      logging_service          = "logging.googleapis.com/kubernetes"
      monitoring_service       = "monitoring.googleapis.com/kubernetes"
      name                     = local.ws_vars["cluster-name"]
      network                  = "projects/${local.ws_vars["project-id"]}/global/networks/${local.ws_vars["network"]}"
      project                  = local.ws_vars["project-id"]
      subnetwork               = "projects/${local.ws_vars["project-id"]}/regions/us-east4/subnetworks/${local.ws_vars["network"]}"
    
      #Figure out how to enable notifications and add pubsub topic for that.
    
    
      ip_allocation_policy {
        #cluster_ipv4_cidr_block = local.ws_vars["cidr-block"]
        cluster_secondary_range_name  = "subnet-pods"
        services_secondary_range_name = "subnet-services"
      }
    
      addons_config {
        horizontal_pod_autoscaling {
          disabled = false
        }
    
        http_load_balancing {
          disabled = false
        }
    
        network_policy_config {
          disabled = false
        }
    
        gcs_fuse_csi_driver_config {
          enabled = true
        }
      }
    
      database_encryption {
        state = "DECRYPTED"
      }
    
      maintenance_policy {
        daily_maintenance_window {
          start_time = "01:00"
        }
      }
    
      network_policy {
        enabled  = true
        provider = "CALICO"
      }
    
      private_cluster_config {
        enable_private_endpoint = false
        enable_private_nodes    = true
        master_ipv4_cidr_block  = "172.14.0.0/28"
      }
    
      release_channel {
        channel = local.ws_vars["channel"]
      }
    
      timeouts {}
    
      vertical_pod_autoscaling {
        enabled = true
      }
    
      workload_identity_config {
        workload_pool = "${local.ws_vars["project-id"]}.svc.id.goog"
      }
}
```

So why is it giving me the error: `unsupported block type`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to **upgrade** your Google Cloud Platform Provider. Support for `gcs_fuse_csi_driver_config` is rather new, and you are probably using old version of the provider.

Comment: You are correct. That was it. I could swear I was on the latest provider but I wasn't. Wow it's that new.

Comment: As I mentioned in the above comment it worked. You have to update the provider. `terraform init -upgrade`

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle Ah OK. You haven't accepted the answer so I thought it did not help you.

Comment: I thought I did but clearly not thanks.